# Escape forward slash character in Hibernate Search / Lucene

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate search 4.2, Lucene 3.6.

I have following column in the domain:

```
@Column(name = "summarycontent")
@Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES)
public String getSummarycontent() {
    return this.summarycontent;
}
```

In database I have data: `abcdef dsfasdf 14/12 fdfdf`.

When performing the query `query: +summarycontent:14/12~0.3` it returns no result.

I think it is because Lucene hasn't escaped forward slash character in the word "14/12".

Please help me to handle Lucene search with forward flash character in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the different tokenizers available in Lucene, as I think both the Classic and Standard tokenizer throw away '/' during tokenizing.